# Way to iterate with different grid sizes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am unable to find information on how to achieve solution to the problem below:
I have in a row 5 grids of size md={2}, md={3}, md={2}, md={2}, md={3}
Now I have to loop it as below, but as grid sizes are different, how to manage them?

```
 <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Grid container>
              {componentData.map((data, index) => {
                return (
                  <Grid item md={} key={index}>
 // closing tags
```

Comment: What if `componentData` array would have more than 5 items? If it can have only 5 items, then you can just write `componentData[0]`, `componentData[1]` .... so on. Or you can use array [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

1. Add the grid size to `componentData`, so you can access it in your `map`-function: `<Grid item md={data.gridSize} key={index}>`
2. Define an array that specifies the grid sizes in order, which you can then also access in your `map` by the `index`:

```
const gridSizes = [2,3,2,2,3];
...
<Grid item md={gridSizes[index]} key={index}>
```